# Obx - Rebuilding a list on variable change

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to make a stories progress bar.
I have a PageView that shows a new video per page, and a progress bar on top that should show the progress of each PageView when I scroll to it.
The problem is the stories bar only updates the very first progress bar. I need them all to keep listening to the updates.

Video progress code:

```
RxDouble getVideoProgress(int storyBarIndex) {
if (storyBarIndex < pageIndex.value) {
  return 1.0.obs;
} else if (storyBarIndex == pageIndex.value) {
  final properVideoController = Get.put(
      ProperVideoController(video: pageVideo!.value),
      tag: ValueKey(pageVideo!.value.uid + '_' + user.authUid + 'tt')
          .toString());
  return properVideoController.videoProgress;
} else {
  return 0.0.obs;
}
```

}

ListView code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GetBuilder<ProfileViewController>(
  init: ProfileViewController(),
  builder: (controller) => Container(
    width: Get.width,
    child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: ((context, constraints) => Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 4,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: itemCount,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return _ProgressBarStep(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth / 6.2,
                          index: index,
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ))),
  ),
);
```

}

Single Story bar widget

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GetBuilder<ProfileViewController>(
    init: ProfileViewController(),
    builder: (controller) {
      return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
          child: Obx(
            () {
   
              return LinearPercentIndicator(
                barRadius: Radius.circular(20),
                animation: true,
                width: width,
                lineHeight: 9.0,
                percent: controller.getVideoProgress(index).value,
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
                backgroundColor: TabooColors.darkBlueGrey,
                progressColor: TabooColors.red,
              );
            },
          ));
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the GetBuilder widget and just use the Obx it would work. Need to add Get.put(ProfileViewController()); above the Widget build() method. I hope this might help you. Please go through the docs: https://pub.dev/packages/get

When we use GetBuilder then we also need to call the update() method in GetxController class to update the UI

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).